# If $u$ is perpendicular to $v$ and $w$, then $u$ is perpendicular to $v + 2 w$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> True or false (give a reason if true or a counterexample if false):
>
> (a) If $u$ is perpendicular (in three dimensions) to $v$ and $w$, those vectors $v$ and $w$ are parallel.
>
> (b) If $u$ is perpendicular to $v$ and $w$, then $u$ is perpendicular to $v + 2 w$,
>
> (c) If $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular unit vectors then $\lVert u - v \rVert =\sqrt2$

For (a) I think the answer is false because $v$ and $w$ could be going in different directions which means they can't be parallel.

But I have no idea how to firgure out b and c. Any ideas?

Comment: hint: in general: $(v+2w) \cdot u=v\cdot u+ 2w \cdot u$

Comment: hint 2: in general: $(rw) \cdot u= r\cdot (w \cdot u)$ if $r$ is a scalar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know the dot product? That can answer both questions.

(b) We have $u\cdot v=0$ and $u\cdot w=0$. Now expand $u\cdot (v+2w)$.

(c) We have $u\cdot v=0$, $u\cdot u=1$, $v\cdot v=1$. Now expand $\sqrt{(u-v)\cdot (u-v)}=\| u-v\|$.

As for (a), consider $u=(1,0,0),\ v=(0,1,0),\ w=(0,0,1)$.

Comment: for (b), when I expand I get $u \cdot v + u \cdot 2w$ and since u and v are orthogonal $u \cdot v$ is zero and we know u and w are orthogonal but does that mean u is orthogonal to 2w?

Comment: @idknuttin: Another property of the dot product is $u\cdot 2w=2(u\cdot w)=2(0)$, as Andres Mejia wrote in a comment. So yes, $u$ is orthogonal to $2w$.

Comment: I am confused with (c), under the radical that is a multiplication sign not a dot product, so if I expand I will be multiplying the vectors, not taking advantage of the previous information you provided?

Comment: @idknuttin: In (c) that is a dot product under the radical. The dot product does follow many of the properties of the usual multiplication. Use the FOIL method or the distributive property to expand the dot product. All three given data will be used after you do the expansion to get the final answer. You will get $\sqrt 2$.